# WCF rest service not work with set multiple binding 'true' in iis express

Tags: wcf, rest, iis, model-view-controller

WCF Rest service not work with set multiple binding 'true' in iis express.
i run service from visual studio in iis express and set 2 binding address 
1. localhost  2. my PC ip address .
i want to debug service in visual studio from service implemented in android project.
if i set multiplesitebinding 'true' then its gives error of relative address.
and if i set binding true then can not run project with 2 binding address.
so my question is that how to debugge service in visual studio.
and what should be my webconfig of wcf services.
my web config looh like this

```
<behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="LotOfObjectsBehavior">
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="ExtendedConfiguration" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="524288">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
          <security mode="None">
            <message establishSecurityContext="false"/>
          </security>

        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WebBinding" />

      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services> 
      <service name="Nop.Plugin.Misc.WebServices.NopService" behaviorConfiguration="LotOfObjectsBehavior">

        <endpoint binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ExtendedConfiguration" contract="Nop.Plugin.Misc.WebServices.INopService" />
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:1111/Plugins/Misc.WebServices/Remote/NopService.svc/web" behaviorConfiguration="web"
                  bindingConfiguration="WebBinding" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="Nop.Plugin.Misc.WebServices.INopService" />
        <endpoint address="Mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />

        <!--<host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://192.168.1.15:8080/Plugins/Misc.WebServices/Remote"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>-->
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
```

Comment: service is use from other pc connected in LAN.

Comment: Your endpoint address cannot have "http://localhost:1111" Just change the address to "rest" or something similar which is different from your first endpoint (with wshttpbinding) and that should work. Since its on IIS express I am assuming the address would be something like : http://localhost/nopservice/rest

Comment: i solve thi questions ... I just add base address as commented above. just uncomment and change in endpoint addrest as ="web". every thing work fine... Thanks